# How to do Mapnik <ElseFilter /> in TileMill CartoCSS

Tags: mapbox, mapnik, tilemill

I'm trying to realize mapnik-XML block in TileMill CartoCSS like this (!!! symbolizers in rules aren't overlaping !!!):

```
<Rule>
    <Filter>[attr_1]=value_1 and [attr_2]=value_2</Filter>
    <LineSymbolizer ... />
</Rule>
.
.
<Rule>
    <Filter>[attr_1]=value_3 and [attr_2]=value_4</Filter>
    <PolygonSymbolizer .../>    
</Rule>

<Rule>
    <ElseFilter/>
    <TextSymbolizer .../>
</Rule>
```

And I didn't find in documentation how to make the else-filter.

```
[attr_1 = value_1] [attr_2 = value_2] {
    ::line-symb {
        line-color: @color;
    }
}
.
.
[attr_1 = value_3] [attr_2 = value_4] {
    ::polygon-symb {
        polygon-fill: @color;
    }
}

// <ElseFilter/> ...
```

Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

There's no equivalent to `else`: think of CartoCSS as CSS, which also doesn't have an 'else': you would just write a rule that applies to the general case. So, if you're styling a layer by its attributes, the `else` is expressed by making a rule that just applies to the layer, with no attribute filters.